# Called child´s constant not available in static function in parent

Tags: php, class, object, parent-child, self

I have a static function in a class that needs to be called from several child classes. I need a constant from the calling child class to be available in that function. To have these constants available in other places, the child classes have a function that returns the value of that constant (php 5.2.9).

However, when in the parent class, I can´t seem to access that constant, not with the function nor directly. Is that even possible in php 5.2.9 or do I need to pass it as an argument?

This is a simple version of the code:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    static function DoSomething() {
        $not_working = self::show_const();
        $not_working_either = self::SOME_CONST;

        return 'working';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    const SOME_CONST = 'some string';

    function show_const() {
        return self::SOME_CONST;
    }
}

$result = ChildClass::DoSomething();
```

**Edit:** the error generated is:

- Call to undefined method ParentClass::show_const()    (for function)
- Undefined class constant 'SOME_CONST'    (using self::SOME_CONST)

Comment: What's the error message that's being generated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do isn't going to work pre 5.3. The problem here is *early* static binding versus *late* static binding. The `self` keyword binds early, so it only looks in the class where it is used to resolve symbols. The magic constant `__CLASS__` or the function `get_class()` won't work either, these do early static binding as well. For this reason PHP 5.3 extended the `static` keyword to mean late binding when used as `static::some_method()`.

So in 5.3 this would work:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
  public static function DoSomething() {
    return static::show_const();
    // also, you could just do
    //return static::SOME_CONST;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  const SOME_CONST = 'some string';
  public static function show_const() {
    return self::SOME_CONST;
  }
}

$result = ChildClass::DoSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. By the way, the only reason I´m using a function to return the constant, is that it seems the only way to have it available on objects in php < 5.3 ...

Comment: +1 The lack of LSB can really make developing OO code in PHP (pre 5.3) a pain.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make ChildClass extend parent class::

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
```

**Edit:**

You're trying to refer to a constant and method in the child class from the parent class which doesn't know the child class' constant exists. It's a scope issue. The child can refer to the parent's methods and constants but not vice versa.

Comment: That´s an error on my side in the example, I´ve corrected the question.

Comment: Obviously you are right, as it is not working, but I am actually calling the child class, not the parent class (although the function resides in the parent class..), so it would seem logical to me that it´s properties would be available. Thanks anyway!